# Can we use Response.Flush () instead of Response.End()

Tags: c#, asp.net, response, httpcontext, response.redirect

`Response.End()` generates `ThreadAbortException`.

Using `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest` in place of it doesn't solve the problem.

So, can we use `Response.Flush()` instead of `Response.End()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Response.Flush()` is send to the browser what is on buffer, but is not stop the processing of the page, so it will continue the execution of the next steps.

What is `Response.End()` do **is to stop the execution steps on the next function call in the asp.net Page Life Cycle**.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

And that's why it need to throw an exception, to throw out of the loop of the series of call.

One alternative is the `Response.Close()` but this also is not stop the execution steps and probably you have some other error if you try to send something after the close of the connection with the browser. if you do `Response.Close()` you need to also do `Flush()` just before you call it or else browser gets unpredictable data.

you can also read : [Redirect to a page with endResponse to true VS CompleteRequest and security thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641143/redirect-to-a-page-with-endresponse-to-true-vs-completerequest-and-security-thre)

Answer (score 4):

Use the condition before download the file `Response.IsClientConnected` -

```
if (Response.IsClientConnected)
 {
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(@"yourpath" + fileName));
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
  }
```

It's working for me well after lot of struggle. I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

No! You cannot!
You can

```
Response.SuppressContent = true;
```

Comment: You should elaborate why you cannot and your solution in your answer.

Comment: Read about Flush() help. This will counting to load the page content and will not send interaction to browser. Only SuppressContent = true and End() will do that.